# how to apply if condition in Hibernate queries in grails

Tags: sql, grails, hql

i am using SpringSourceTool for grails project developement .
i had this requirement to execute a query with some if condition in it , first I tried the query in sql query browser
and it works fine
but when i try to access it in grails , the result set is null .

my sql query for DummyData ,

```
select week , month , emp_name , sum(emp_salary),sum(if(emp_age=19,emp_bonus,0)) from dummy_data order by week;
```

this query works just fine

now when i try the same in grails domain class execute query

```
def myList = DummyData.executeQuery("select week,month,empName,sum(empSalary),sum(if(empAge=19,empBonus,0)) from DummyData group by week")
```

Comment: Just to be sure your data is properly in the db, if you run `DummyData.list()`, what do you get back?

Comment: @JeffStorey :when i dont appy the if condition , i get the data in the list , and in my database i get the data with if condition too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you don't want to execute raw SQL queries against a hibernate database because the ORM stores things in tables in a much more complex way than how you might store the data (so it can properly map to java objects). You're not selecting particular fields from a database, but rather you're selecting objects. So you need to store the data in a way that can be retrieved by hibernate.

I suggest you use the facilities in grails to execute queries against a hibernate database - particularly look at the [Criteria Builder](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)

Comment: +1 for your suggestion , seems legit to me , but before i accept the answer , i better implement so first